# Does OnCollisionEnter2D get called after setting isTrigger to false?

Tags: unity-game-engine

- Collider2D **A** is a trigger. Collider2D **B** isn't.
- They start colliding.
- Collider **A**'s isTrigger property is set to false in code.
- Does OnCollisionEnter2D get called on either **A** or **B**? In the same
  cycle or the next one?

Comment: Actually, Are you trying to see if you can have a trigger set it's trigger ability to false (In OnTriggerEnter2D), and then make OnCollisionEnter call because they are now "colliding"?

Comment: The code that sets A.isTrigger to true is placed in a MonoBehaviour on the A's gameObject, but it runs independently of A and B's collision status.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the next frame, unless I'm missing something here they have now collided and instead of calling "OnCollisionEnter" they should be calling "OnCollisionStay", so to answer your question directly: No.

Refer to the [Unity Colliders Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) for more.

Comment: I concur.  The linked documentation doesn't explicitly state that that's what happens, but this part, "However, you can also use the physics engine simply to detect when one collider enters the space of another without creating a collision" would seem to heavily imply it.